# Merge dicts from a list of dicts based on some key/value pair

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dicts shown below , I want to merge some dicts into one based some key/value pair.

```
 [
    {'key': 16, 'value': 3, 'user': 3, 'id': 7}, 
    {'key': 17, 'value': 4, 'user': 3, 'id': 7}, 
    {'key': 17, 'value': 5, 'user': 578, 'id': 7}, 
    {'key': 52, 'value': 1, 'user': 3, 'id': 48}, 
    {'key': 46, 'value': 2, 'user': 578, 'id': 48}
]
```

Now as you can see `dict 1 & 2` have same values for **user** & **id** keys. So it is possible to merge these two dicts like

```
 [
    {'key': [16,17], 'value': [3,4], 'user': 3, 'id': 7}, 
    {'key': [17], 'value': [5], 'user': 578, 'id': 7}, 
    {'key': [52], 'value': [1], 'user': 3, 'id': 48}, 
    {'key': [46], 'value': [2], 'user': 578, 'id': 48}
]
```

means `user & id` value must be unique together.What will be the efficient way to merge (if possible)

Comment: Why lists in merged dictionaries?

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar so that I have values of both merged dicts for `key & value` . If you know better approach there will not an issue.

Comment: I think you should then have `key : [16, 17]` instead of `[17, 4]`

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar Oh yes , My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following function will convert the list of dictionaries to new format:

```
def convert(d):
    res = {}
    for x in d:
        key = (x['user'], x['id'])
        if key in res:
            res[key]['key'].append(x['key'])
            res[key]['value'].append(x['value'])
        else:
            x['key'] = [x['key']]
            x['value'] = [x['value']]
            res[key] = x

    return res.values()
```

It will mutate the original dictionaries and the ordering of dictionaries in the result will be random. When applied to the input it will produce following result:

```
[
    {'id': 7, 'value': [5], 'key': [17], 'user': 578}, 
    {'id': 7, 'value': [3, 4], 'key': [16, 17], 'user': 3}, 
    {'id': 48, 'value': [1], 'key': [52], 'user': 3}, 
    {'id': 48, 'value': [2], 'key': [46], 'user': 578}
]
```

Comment: Thx a lot. A general question. Le us suppose we have list of dict range between 1000 to 10000 . The conversion I am asking will take time and always have performance issues, no doubt about that. But what you think how much time it will take.

Comment: I tested with 1000000 dicts by copying your input 200000 times, the function ran less than 1 second on my laptop. With the numbers you gave I wouldn't be too worried about the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Let `dicts` be your original list of dictionaries. This idea maps unique combinations of user and id to `defaultdict(list)` objects. The final result will be the list of values from that dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
tmp = defaultdict(dict)

for info in dicts:
    tmp[(info['user'], info['id'])].setdefault('key', []).append(info['key'])
    tmp[(info['user'], info['id'])].setdefault('value', []).append(info['value'])

for (user, id_), d in tmp.items(): # python2: use iteritems
    d.update(dict(user=user, id=id_))

result = list(tmp.values()) # python2: tmp.values() already gives a list
del tmp
```

Comment: Thx a lot. as you can see @niemmi also answered my question. But I am more concerned with performance. And i don'y know which one will have better performance. what you think ? you can refer to my comment on niemmi question.

Comment: @user5594493 I think the performance will be similar. Why don't you try it with the `timeit` module?

Comment: Thx I'll do. In between Collections spell is wrong in import .

Comment: this is pretty cool, could you give some more explanation for the last lines? also wouldn't `tmp = defaultdict(defaultdict(list))` be more elegant than `setdefault`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity I ran the same test as I described in my comments on your code with relevant changes for python2. It seems that your approach is about 30-40% slower but this obviously depends on the exact input used. The difference is probably caused by the fact this solution iterates twice over the input in case that most `user`/`id` pairs are unique.

Comment: @niemmi well, it also has one if/else check less. Maybe the difference comes from building the dictionary when `update` is called. Did you exclude the import from the timing?

Comment: @timgeb: I excluded both `import` & `del` at the end and used `iteritems` instead `items` as you commented. I also removed the extra list generation when constructing the result. I ran both versions multiple times since the results tend to vary a bit between runs,

Comment: @niemmi my guess is `dict(user=user, id=id_)`. I think this reads nicely, but constructs an unecessary dict. You could try to set the keys manually here in two lines, i.e. `d['user'] = user; d['id'] = id_`.

Comment: @timgeb: Change will improve the performance maybe couple percents with the input I was using. Even if all 1000000 dicts have unique `user`/`id` pairs the improvement is less than 10%.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following aggregate function:

```
def aggregate(lst):
    new = {}
    for d in lst:
        new.setdefault((d['user'], d['id']), []).append(d)
    for k, d in new.items():
        if len(d) > 1:
            keys, values = zip(*[(sub['key'], sub['value']) for sub in d])
            user, id_ = k
            yield {'key': keys, 'value': values, 'user': user, 'id': id_}
        else:
            yield d[0]

print list(aggregate(lst))
[{'id': 7, 'value': 5, 'key': 17, 'user': 578},
 {'id': 7, 'value': (3, 4), 'key': (16, 17), 'user': 3},
 {'id': 48, 'value': 1, 'key': 52, 'user': 3},
 {'id': 48, 'value': 2, 'key': 46, 'user': 578}]
```

Comment: It won't work! You have mispelt `aggregate` at the end of the code!